# Select data from multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I Have a dynamic query where i need to send database names as comma separated values and retreive data from different databases can u help me out..i have the following query

```
Decalre @DBname nvarchar(max);
Declare @Selectstring nvarchar(max);

set @Selectstring='

  select    

      Userid,
      UserName,
      CreatedOn,
      IsActive as Status,
      LastLoggedin

   from 
        '+@DBname+'.dbo.UserDetails'

    execute sp_executesql @query=@Selectstring
```

I am executing this using dynamic query..i want to send @Dbname value as

```
  set @dbname='dbname1,dbname2,dbname3'
```

Each DB has this table and i want to get data from all this tables from different databases..Please help me how to do this

Comment: Try to make it work with just one database first and then you can expand that solution to loop over database names in a comma separated string using a split string function or the likes.

Comment: When using Dynamic SQL like this, you should always be careful to not expose yourself to SQL injection as is common by doing methods such as this. There are several examples online of ways to protect yourself and it's outside the scope of this question, but I felt should be pointed out. A simple example would be suppose: `SET @DBname='dbname1; UPDATE dbname1.dbo.UserDetails SET IsActive = 1; SELECT * FROM dbname1'` which would still work for your example but would result in changing the underlying data

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way that assumes there are 3 databases on the same server (db1, db2, db3) that have a common table called: table_1. It uses sys.databases (if sql2005 or newer) to loop through the databases with a slightly difference in the way you build the @dbname string where you need to surround each db name with single quotes to correctly use it as part of an IN clause

NOTE: you can change the cursor for a while if you want.

```
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @dbname='''db1'',''db2'',''db3'''

EXEC (
'DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE DB_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tbl.name FROM 
        (SELECT db.name from sys.databases db WHERE db.name IN (' + @DBname + ')) as tbl
    OPEN DB_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR
    INTO @db
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC(''SELECT * FROM '' + @db + ''.dbo.table_1'')
        FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO @db
    END
CLOSE DB_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DB_CURSOR'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dbname varchar(max)
select @dbname = 'master, model, msdb'
declare @sql varchar(max)
select @sql = isnull(@sql,'') 
    + case when @sql is null then '' else ' union all ' end
    + 'select ''' + db.name + ''' dbname, *from ' + db.name + '.dbo.sysfiles'
from sys.databases db
where @dbname like '%' + db.name + '%'

execute (@sql)
```

This assumes the collation of all databases is the same and will return all results in a single result set with the source database name as a column.  However, if you have databases with similar names, such as Database1 and Database10, this would return results for Database1 and Database10 if you passed in Database10 as a parameter because Database1 is a substring of Database10.

You are much better off using a table variable as input or otherwise converting the csv string into a table with a split function and then joining to the new table instead of using "where @dbname like..." syntax.